# How can I access the file name a test runs in from inside the afterTest hook in a wdio config file?

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io, wdio-jasmine

I am trying to access the file name each test runs in from the `afterTest` hook in my wdio config file. However, none of the parameters provided to the hook includes the file name. I tried maybe getting the file name from the `onWorkerStart` hook, since the `specs` parameter provided to that hook includes the file name, so something like this:

```
onWorkerStart(cid, caps, specs) {
  const fileName = specs[0];
}
```

But I'm not sure how to access the `fileName` variable I created in the `onWorkerStart` hook in my `afterTest` hook. I tried maybe using it as a global variable:

```
onWorkerStart(cid, caps, specs) {
  global.fileName = specs[0];
}
afterTest() {
  console.log(global.fileName);
}
```

But this just prints "undefined". And if I print it from the `onWorkerStart` hook too, it does in fact print the name of the file from there first, but then "undefined" from the `afterTest` hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I was unaware that global variables in the wdio config had to be made inside the `before` hook, and luckily, the `before` hook includes a parameter `specs` which contains the file name. So all that needs to be done to access the file name in all the other hooks is to define `global.specFileName = specs[0]` inside the `before` hook. And now `specFileName` can be used in the `afterTest` hook.